# issue with flask not updating query used to fill a html select, not sure how to refreh it

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a flask app which is a form, the structure is the following:

**my_form.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import (StringField, TextAreaField, IntegerField, BooleanField, RadioField, SelectField, DateField)
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length
import sqlite3

def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/test.db')
    # conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn

# conn = get_db_connection()
# campus_list = conn.execute('SELECT name FROM table').fetchall()
# conn.close()


class cap_form(FlaskForm):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    my_list = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM campus').fetchall()
    
    conn.close()

    my_data = SelectField('fields', choices=my_list, validators=None)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, jsonify, request
from my_form import cap_form
import sqlite3



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my_key'


@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    form = cap_form()
    data_key = form.my_data.data

    if data_key != "":
        query = insert info to a table
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="row mb-3 text-end">
        <div class="col-3 themed-grid-col">
            <p>
                {{ form.my_data.label }}
                {{form.my_data}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So everything works well with one exception, the issue is that as you can see I fill the select my_data in the my_form.py file and it gets render in index.html, the thing is that when I insert more data into my table(using another form) it is not shown on my_data select until I "re deploy" the project, I can't figure a way on how to re-run the query that populates that select exactly after I insert new date in that particular table the data.

The way I did it that way instead of something like:

```
{% for i in list %}
    <OPTION value={{value}}>{{data}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</SELECT>
```

it's to use it like this {{form.my_data}} and be able to reference it with ease for some other fields.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

I tried using this piece of code render_template('index.html', form=form) in other sections to make a "refresh" but it doesn't work

Comment: You could have it refresh itself every 60 seconds.  The key is that the refresh/reload has to come from the web page, not from the server.